# Provider not updating custom widget when value changes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

My provider is used inside a custom widget that is used as `ListTile` inside the parent widget .

The provider is inside a `stream` that fetches data from a `Firebase database`, when the stream is triggered it stores the new data inside the provider as a `Map`.

The provider is called `LastMessage` and the `Map` is called `messageMap`, new data gets added using the function `updateMap` :

```
var messageInstance = Provider.of<global.LastMessage>(context, listen: false);
StreamSubscription<Event> updates;

// roomId is a string that is used as a key
updates = ref.child(RoomId).onChildAdded.listen((event) async{ // the stream works correctly and the new data gets stored 
      String _x = await getLastMessage();// a function that gets the data from the database 
      messageInstance.updateMap(RoomId, _x);
    });
```

```
class LastMessage extends ChangeNotifier{
  Map<String, String> messageMap = {};

  void updateMap(String RoomID, String lastMessage){
    messageMap[RoomID] = lastMessage;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Now the problem is that even after `messageMap` is updated the widget doesn't get rebuilt when `listen` is set to `false`, although it works when `listen` is `true` but it makes the whole app very slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using StreamBuilder instead of provider to update the widget

Answer (score 1):

Widget will be rebuilt only if the listener is true.
If the listener is false then the widget will not be rebuilt when you call notifyListeners();

Comment: This is not the case since I have used a similar thing to update a `ListView` and it worked even when `listen` was set to `false` @StasVo

Comment: False value of listen made specially  for prevent update widget by provider. If you will provide code of case when your widget has been updated with the False value, I will try explain why why did it happen.

Comment: It's a simple code actually, there is a `List` of the custom widget I mentioned in my question, it's called `Contact`. I reference the provider the same way as above with `listen: false`, in the widget that renders the `ListView` there is `List = instance.contactList` and then the list is displayed using `ListView` and when a new element is added to the list using a function inside the provider I call `notifyListeners()` and the `ListView` gets rebuilt. If you didn't understand what is exactly happening I will try to share more of the project using github @StasVo

Comment: I should also note that I use `ListView.builder` @StasVo

Comment: I think that share code on github will be better for understand.

Comment: This is my first time sharing code using github so apologies if I have done it badly. [The repository](https://github.com/Anan-Saadi/Provider) @StasVo

Comment: One of mistakes which I clearly see there is that you have this line: ContactList().notifyListeners(); in updateMap method of class LastMessage. There you create new object of ContactList. Its not same object which use your provider. For call notifyListeners() you need to access same object which was created in Provider for update widget which listen changes.

Comment: I accidentally forgot to remove it but it was an attempt to update the list since `ListView` is generated using `ContactList`, but it ended up doing a similar thing to setting the `listen` to true where it seams like its constantly updating the list many times a second @StasVo

Comment: Why do you want to rebuild whole ListView when there changed LastMessage in one of ListView items? If ListView item have some changes as for example changes of name, lastMessage etc, then possible to rebuild only one listview item widget instead to rebuild whole ListView.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do, update the item widget when lastMessage changes but so far its not working, updating the ListView was something I tried and didn't work @StasVo

Comment: If you want to rebuild item of ListView (update LastMessage of list item) by use Provider, then you should create Provider for every list item. I mean that neet to wrap every listItem by Provider. I see that you created Provider for update LastMessage in root of your app but its not correct because every your listitem have own state and should be updated in separate way from each other.

Comment: Wrapping every listitem in a provider isn't really feasible, is there another way to update listItem? @StasVo

Comment: Is it feasible. Its very easy. Just wrap widget which you return in ListView.builder by ChangeNotifierProvider.  If you dont want  to use Provider, you can just make your Contact widget to be StatefulWidget and call setState() when you want to rebuild Contact widget.